# Does Windows authentication use aspnet_Users table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, security, iis

This may seem like a silly question but I need some information. Does Windows authentication use `aspnet_Users` table at all? I created a asp.net application with *windows authentication* and it works fine however I was under the impression the user must be present in  `aspnet_Users` table (which is not the case.). Is there any setting I can change to make my application check `aspnet_Users` table to verify the user or do I have to do it manually? Thanks for your comments in advance.

Comment: I should also add, I used lightswitch and they made used of the aspnet_users table with windows authentication. The username must be correct [domain/username]  if a user is to get access to the application. I would like such a feature on asp.net applications.

Answer (score 5):

No, it does not use that table. That table is if you're using ASP.NET Membership.

To use Windows Authentication, your user will need to be set up in Active Directory. If you want to use a mix of Integrated Windows Authentication and Membership or Identity, then things get very sticky.

Comment: I believe Windows Authentication can also use a local user account on the machine of the server (not just Active Directory)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already have my users set up and its working fine. I just would like to add an extra layer as such utilise the aspnet_users tables. Thats the reason behind my question.

Comment: @XenoPuTtSs I can't confirm that but I suppose it makes sense.

Comment: @XenoPuTtSs that is interesting. Any materials or links on how to do this?

Comment: @Mavs The extra layer you want to add is basicly "I don't want to use Windows Authentication"  but something that looks like "ASP.Net Membership Provider".  If you want to do both, then you will need to do some work yourself (at least 3 years ago it was a lot of work) to build a custom Memership provider.

here is a link to what I did.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8154570/1007723

Comment: @XenoPuTtSs valid point. The reason for using windows authentication is to eliminate a user entering username and password. However, I also want to prevent some users from having access to my application. Using windows authentication allows everyone in active directory to access my application.

Comment: @Mavs In that case I'd use Windows authentication, then implement a filter (for MVC) or a check at the beginning of the pipeline in Global.asax (for Web Forms) with logic to prevent the user from using the site, perhaps redirecting to a page telling them how to request access.

Comment: @mason that is one way i am thinking about doing it. Seems the easiest route. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Mavs have you read this article  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323176 ?  It has some info on restricting access.